# How to get a mini calendar webpart like an asp.net calendar webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calendar

I would like to display a mini calendar as webpart on a sharepoint page.
    I have tried all the calendar views but nothing satisfied the requirement.
I need something like an asp.net calendar that user can just over a date or click to see there events.
Any ideas where i can find something or build it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78532/Event-Calendar-Listing-Web-Part-SharePoint-2010) on Codeproject.

I have used it before with a few modifications, it works pretty well. You can remove the bottom part with the event listing if you only want the calendar.

Comment: Great Loius looks nice but i do i remove the event listings

Comment: You edit the code :). Actually I think it has a webpart property for that ("ShowListing", from the description on the web page)

Answer (score 1):

you can check out my blog (had to create exactly what you are questioning for my company). used javascript

http://designandaligndevelopment.com/Programming/Sharepoint-UPDATED-10-15-2012-custom-calendar-webpart-using-css-javascript.aspx

Comment: Link is broken..

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the Out of the Box filter web parts, the Date Filter Web Part is the one you can use. Check out a couple of links:

http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2009/09/16/sharepoint-date-filter-filtering-a-list-by-greater-than-or.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA010033786.aspx

Comment: Ash i need a Mini Calendar SharePoint Web Part.
A calendar but a small one :)
Thanks

Comment: check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78532/Event-Calendar-Listing-Web-Part-SharePoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps using SharePoint designer- Please check this link - http://www.indrasani.com/sharepoint-designer-calendar-control/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free app from Office Store to display a Mini Calendar on your site. Works in both Online and on premise environments.

[Office Store - Artezio Mini Calendar](https://store.office.com/mini-calendar-WA104154789.aspx?assetid=WA104154789)

Answer (score 0):

I also found a nice solution from Erik Swensons blog

http://erikswenson.blogspot.de/2013/04/small-calendar-for-sharepoint-2010-2013.html

Really nice css customization of the standard calendar webpart

Thanks to Erik.

```
2010 CSS link reference in Master Page: 
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/smallcalendar.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>

2010 CSS: 
/**** Small Calendar ***/ 
.ms-acal-item{height: 10px !important;} 
.ms-acal-sdiv, 
.ms-acal-mdiv, 
.ms-acal-ctrlitem, 
.ms-acal-month-weeksel, 
.ms-acal-title{display: none;} 
.ms-acal-summary-itemrow TD DIV{height: 15px !important;}

2013 Content Editor Web Part CSS: 
<style> 
/**** Small Calendar ***/ 
.ms-acal-item{height: 10px !important;} 
.ms-acal-sdiv, 
.ms-acal-mdiv, 
.ms-acal-ctrlitem, 
.ms-acal-month-weeksel, 
.ms-acal-title, 
.ms-acal-month-top span{display: none;} 
.ms-acal-summary-itemrow TD DIV{height: 15px !important;} 
</style>
```